# How to use iteration of lambda in Python

Tags: python, lambda, iterator

Thank you guys. I find I cannot post my question on internet.

However, it is really helpful to me.

Comment: Is there any code you can show?

Comment: I sense an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 5):

Compose will need 3 arguments: the function to compose, the number of times to compose it, and the initial argument.  So if you want to evaluate f(f(f(7))) you would call compose(f, 3, 7).

```
def compose(f, n, x):
   if n == 0: return x
   return compose(f, n-1, f(x))
```

It's occurred to me that maybe this isn't exactly what you want.  Perhaps you want to be able to write `g = compose(f, 3)` and then call `g(7)`.  This requires only a minor modification:

```
def compose(g, m):
    def composer(f, n, x):
       if n == 0: return x
       return compose(f, n-1, f(x))
    return lambda x: composer(g, m, x)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand correctly, but I believe you expect compose() to return a function. In that case, this would work:

```
def compose(f, n):
   def composed_f(x):
      result = x

      for i in range(n):
         result = f(result)
      return result

   return composed_f
```

So, if you write:

```
a = compose((lambda x:x*2), 5)
print a(1)
```

You will get 32

Answer (score 0):

use saulspatz's compose and a lambda

```
cubed = lambda x: x**3

def compose(f, n, x):
   if n == 0: return x
   return compose(f, n-1, f(x))

print(compose(cubed,2,2))

512
```

Answer (score 0):

While this can be implemented concisely using recursion, an iterative solution is more efficient and won't break for large values of `n`.

```
def compose(f, n):
    def iterated_f(x):
        rv = x
        while n > 0:
            rv = f(rv)
        return rv
    return iterated_f
```